# Wordpress query 3 featured images post

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to query 3 featured images post. If post have no featured image then its not showing. If post have a featured image then show the 3 featured post. How can I do that?

```
global $wp_query;
global $paged;
$temp       = $wp_query; 
$wp_query   = null; 
$wp_query   = new WP_Query(); 
$wp_query->query('showposts=3&post_type=post&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC'.'&paged='.$paged);
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();

the_post_thumbnail();
the_title();

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use following function. I tested and confirmed its working for me.

```
$recent_query = new WP_Query(
                             array(
                                    'post_type'      => 'post', 
                                    'orderby'        => 'date',    
                                    'order'          => 'DESC',
                                    'post_status'    => 'publish', 
                                    'posts_per_page' => 3,
                                    'meta_query'     => array(
                                                              array( 
                                                                     'key' => '_thumbnail_id'
                                                                   ), //Show only posts with featured images
                                                               )
                                   )

                            ); 


if ( $recent_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $recent_query->have_posts() ) : $recent_query->the_post(); 

        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
        }

        the_title();

    endwhile;

endif;
```

Comment: Hello if this answer help full for you??

Answer (score 0):

Wordpres post thumbnails work with post metas. And thumbnail meta key is `_thumbnail_id`. You can create your query with this meta key. More details: [Wordpress Meta Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query)

Or only include has thumbnail(`_thumbnail_id` meta_key) posts you can use this query:

```
$args = array(
  'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id',
  'posts_per_page' => 3
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```